# jinja2 syntax to escape nested raw block

Tags: jinja2, ansible-template

is it possible to escape the raw block itself so that

```
{% raw %}

foobar,
  {% raw %}
  need this verbatim with the raw block outside
  {% endraw %}

{% endraw %}
```

gets templated out as below ?

```
foobar,
{% raw %}
  need this verbatim with the raw block outside
{% endraw %}
```

I am running templates via ansible which is fed to another system which also uses jinja templating. I can probably work around this but am curios if this use case is somehow supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
foobar, 
{{ '{%' }} raw {{ '%}' }}
need this verbatim with the raw block outside 
{{ '{%' }} endraw {{ '%}' }}
```